# ImageProcessor - Resize to a specified width (automatic height)

Tags: c#, imageprocessor

I'm using the [ImageProcessor](http://imageprocessor.org/) library in my App.

I'm using this code in order to resize to a given specific dimensions ( width+height) :

```
 public static byte[] ResizeImage(byte[] inputFileBytes, int w, int h, ResizeMode resizeMode)
        {
            byte[] photoBytes = inputFileBytes; 

            ISupportedImageFormat format = new JpegFormat { Quality = 70, IsIndexed = false };
            Size size = new Size(w, h);
            using (MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream(photoBytes))
            using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
            {

                using (ImageFactory imageFactory = new ImageFactory(preserveExifData: false))
                {
                    var r = new ResizeLayer(size, resizeMode);

                    imageFactory.Load(inStream)
                        .Resize(r)
                        .Format(format)
                        .Save(outStream);
                }


                return outStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

I invoke it via (This is a crop *example* ):

```
   byte[] servedImage =  ResizeImage(byteArray,[...imgWidth...],
                       [...imgHeight...],ResizeMode.Crop);
```

This all works good.

But now I need to resize the image to a *specific* `width` — And I want the height to be proportional.

I already know that the [Resize method](http://imageprocessor.org/imageprocessor/imagefactory/resize/) has an overload :

```
public ImageFactory Resize(Size size)
```

But I only have the `Width` in the `size` param ( I want the height to be calculated automatically)

**Question**

How can I resize an Image (`byte[]`)to a specific `Width` , maintaining the aspect ration  using  ImageProcessor ?

Comment: The easiest option is going to be to calculate the height. If you have the original width and the desired width, just divide them to get the multiplier, and apply it to the height - job done

Comment: Can't you work out the new height? `ratio = old_height / old_width`, then `new_height = old_width * ratio`

Comment: @CallumBradbury I don't have it. I'm getting a byte array from the user and I'm not going make an image out of it by myself , in order to extract the ratio , and then to tell the library again so it can create the image.... it seems waisty.

Comment: Ah, yes that does complicate matters

Comment: It seems like the Constrain() function is a better fit than the Resize()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the ResizeMode according to the cropping / stretching behavior you are trying to achieve.  The library is designed to accommodate for differences in aspect ratio automatically depending on the chosen value for ResizeMode.

If you want to have the height auto-calculated, pass a 0 for the Height in the Size.

Comment: The code I specified is for cropping - yes. I just showed how I invoke the method. If I remove the crop ( which I don't need it now actually) - How can I reize the image to a specific Width ?

Comment: Oh let me check please :-)

Comment: Excellant . Thank you. BTW , related -  [how come I have a JPG image , I don't resize it - I save it , and the saved image is much bigger](https://i.imgur.com/IclZL0h.jpg) ?

Comment: I don't think the original image was saved with quality = 100, this is some kind of lossy decompression as a result.  Best guess I can make without seeing how the original image was created.

Comment: It's just a given image from the web , isnt a given image is already 100 quality ?

Comment: To my understanding, not necessarily.  Possibly also implementation dependent on the compression algorithm?  I'm not 100% sure

Comment: [btw this is the image](http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/554289489_1280x720.jpg)